# Create zip archive from a list of ByteArrayInputStream and return byte[] array of the archive - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, php-ziparchive, bytearrayinputstream

I want to archive some files that I am receiving from an external source. I receive each of this files as a **ByteArrayInputStream**. In the end I want my method to create the zip archive and **return a byte[] array** so that I can download it later.
I have successfully managed to do this, but the end result is an ZipOutputStream and not the byte[] array that I need.
Any ideeas are appreciated. Thanks!

```
       FileOutputStream fos = null;
       ZipOutputStream zipOut = null;

       try {
           fos = new FileOutputStream(archiveFileName.concat(ReportFormat.ZIP.getFileExtension()));
           zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));

           for (Map.Entry<?, ByteArrayInputStream> entry : mapInputStream.entrySet()) {
               String  fileFromInsiteArchiveName = (String) entry.getKey();
               ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = entry.getValue();

               ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileFromInsiteArchiveName);
               zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
               byte[] tmp = new byte[4 * 1024];
               int size = 0;
               while ((size = inputStream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
                   zipOut.write(tmp, 0, size);
               }
               zipOut.flush();
               inputStream.close();
           }
           zipOut.close();

           return zipOut;

       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           //handle this
       } catch (IOException e) {
           //handle this
       } finally {
           try {
               if (fos != null) fos.close();
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               //handlethis
           }
       }
       return zipOut;
   }
```

Comment: Copy to `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then do `baos.toByteArray()` to get your `byte[]`

Comment: Thank you !!! this works... how could I've been so blind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy to `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then do `baos.toByteArray()` to get your `byte[]`